# UIGrid (Angular JS) - having a dropdown in a table header column

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.5 and am using the UI Grid. I was wondering is there a way to put a drop-down (i.e. a select) in a header column ? I know you can do it within the "data" cells/rows of the table but unsure if it can be done in the header title ?

See the below image link to see a visual of what I mean. I want to put the dropdown into the column header called "Value"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGMOc.png)

Thanks - Ronan.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a filter with selectOptions for displaying a dropdown in the header.

Example:

```
columnDefs: [{ 
              name: 'id', field: 'id'
            }, 
            { 
              name: 'value', field: 'value',
              filter: {
                       type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                       selectOptions: [{ value: '1', label: 'One' }, 
                                       { value: '2', label: 'Two' }]
                      }
             }]
```

For more details check filter section in this link [UI Grid ColumnDef - Filters](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef)

Comment: Hi - That looks great - thanks for that. Can you also have an ng-change on the select ? - i.e.so when I click different values in the select that I can then capture that value (for passing to a REST call)

Thanks - Ro.